# In Visual Studio Code, can I refer to a configuration element from c_cpp_properties.json in tasks.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm working on a C project that should compile under both Linux and MacOS using their respective compilers. I have installed the `C/C++` extension in VS Code and I would like the compilation task in `tasks.json` to pick up the right compiler based on the OS I'm currently on.

If, in my `c_cpp_properties.json` file I have the following (I removed the irrelevant elements):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "compilerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Would it be possible to refer to the `compilerPath` variable in `tasks.json`? And especially without having to state which OS-based configuration? What I 'd like to do is this:

```
 "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "compilation",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${config:compilerPath} -g main.c"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you been able to get a solution for this?

Comment: @GuillermoPrandi I haven't. AFAICT, it's because the file `c_cpp_properties.json` is a configuration file for an extension (in this case, the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension). As such, `tasks.json` can't possibly "know" about things in the configuration files of an extension. Well, it's my understanding as of today.